# Python: Lambda function with multiple conditions based on multiple previous rows

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, conditional-statements

I am trying to define a lambda function that assigns `True` or `False` to a row based on various conditions. There is a column with a Timestamp and what I want is, that if **within the last 10 seconds** (based on the timestamp of the current row **x**) some specific values occurred in other columns of the dataset, the current row **x** gets the `True` or `False` tag.

So basically I have to check whether in the previous **n** rows, **i.e. Timestamp(x) - 10 seconds** value *a* occurred in column *A* **and** value *b* occured in column *B*.

I already looked at the *shift()* function with *freq = 10 seconds* and another attempt looked like that:

`data['Timestamp'][(data['Timestamp']-pd.Timedelta(seconds=10)):data['Timestamp']]`

But I wasn't able to proceed with either of the two options.

Is it possible to start an additional select within a lambda function? If yes, how could that look like?

P.S.: Working with regular *for-loops* **instead of** the lambda function is not an option due to the overall setup of the application/code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this, if I understood correctly:

```py
def create_tag(current_timestamp, df, cols_vals):
    # Before the current timestamp
    mask = (df['Timestamp'] <= current_timestamp)
    # After the current timestamp - 10s
    mask = mask & (df['Timestamp'] >= current_timestamp - pd.to_timedelta('10s'))
    # Filter all dataframe following the mask
    filtered = df[mask]
    # Check if each val of col is present
    present = all(value in filtered[column_name].values for column_name, value in cols_vals.items())
    return present
        
data['Tag'] = data['Timestamp'].apply(lambda x: create_tag(x, data, {'column A': 'a', 'column B', 'b'}))
```

The idea behind this code is, for each timestamp that you have, we're going to apply the `create_tag` function. This takes the current timestamp, the whole dataframe as well as a dictionary containing column names as keys and the respective values you're looking for as values.

Comment: thanks @Xelvoz!
Just two more quick questions:
1. why using all() instead of any()? Not sure if I got it right, but when using all(), won't the code check wether ALL rows in the filtered dataframe contain the values of A and B?
2. this is probably not super computationally efficient, is it?

Comment: 1. all() function is from Python's standard library, it checks if all of the values inside an iterable are True. I do it since you made the "and" bold when you specified that both a and b should be present. 2. You're right, generally using apply could be inefficient, however this is the only method I know of and I use for this kind of problem, still more efficient than a for loop.